# List of questions to review/edit

Tags: feature-request, edits

Could we have a "to-review" page? Posts that might not be of top quality could be submitted for review automatically by the little green unicorns (aka "servers") running StackOverflow.

Possible "to-review" questions/answers can be automatically be detected if they contain:

- Errors in punctuation (Under/Excessive/Incorrect Capitalization Like This, no periods, etc).
- *Extremely* long run on sentences.
- A large number of spelling errors.
- [Multiple !?!?!?!?s](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99871/152657)
- Non-english. (i.e. Unformatted code.)
- Incorrect formatting.
- 1337 & 07H3r vv13rd txt, lol!
- Etc

Comment: [`/review/low-quality-posts`](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts?pagesize=15&filter=day)

Comment: I bet a lot of the "bad-post-indicators" you mention are already in the bad-post-detection code already in place for the questions.  Of course the details on how it works are not mentioned so people don't have a systematic way to circumvent the system.

Comment: @Tim Of course, 90% of those low-quality posts are just code samples without much explanation, rather than posts with grammatical/spelling errors, incorrect formatting, and poor exposition in general.

Comment: @Chris Yeah, it would be nice if those received more weight against being considered "low quality"

Answer (score 1):

I've been maintaining a small [editing guide](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/830/editing-tips-and-tricks/831#831) for Ask Ubuntu, maybe some of those can apply here.

It would be nice if there was a collection of SEDE queries that people could try for a while, then see if they are useful, and then have that feedback sent to the SE team so they could incorporate it into /review. For example, I've been searching for "problem" in question titles and usually that seems to be indicative of a too-generic title. Low hanging fruit I guess!