# ¿Can we automatically remove inverted question marks from question titles and bodies?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, questions

You see this often in questions of users with [Spanish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_question_and_exclamation_marks) as mother tongue. The `¿` has utterly no meaning in correct English. In my opinion it can always safely be auto-removed. This saves the editors from some [extra effort](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7730505/revisions).

I haven't ever seen the inverted exclamation mark `¡` being used, but perhaps this can be added to the blacklist as well.

---

**Update**: as being an avid SO user I did not immediately realize that meta.stackoverflow.com also covers meta.stackexchange.com; I'd like to clarify more that this request was intentionally targeted on stackoverflow.com alone, not really on other SE sites. I'm also not sure if this kind of features can be configured on a per-site level, but I'd imagine that this is possible.

Comment: Fair enough. `¿` is a part of the [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) but not in first position, so this should be fine

Comment: I'm hesitant to support the expansion of automatic editing of user-generated content.  I don't envision any unintended consequences with this particular issue, but part of the problem is that these features get implemented when there **are** unintended consequences that were merely not envisioned by those doing the implementation...

Comment: @Michael: currently, an exclamation mark in title will already be turned into a question mark (I believe, there are more automatic editings as well, but no other comes to mind right now). After a second thought, I think that it maybe don't need to be implemented for question bodies. At least, if the automatic edit also raises a clear warning upon submit, it should be clear enough to the enduser.

Comment: @Chichiray I think converting exclamation points into question marks is also a **bad** **idea**?

Comment: @Michael: I had indeed also my doubts about this one. But that is not what my feature request is about. I am also confident that it's less bad.

Comment: It's less bad until for instance a hypothetical Spanish.SE starts to complain (as one possible exception).

Comment: @Michael: I'd imagine that this kind of stuff is configureable on a per-site level as many other things.

Comment: Naturally, this would negatively impact [certain future proposals](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14456/spanish-language-usage), but wouldn't be the [first title fix](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99871/can-should-we-get-rid-of-multiple-punctuation-marks/100104#100104) that hosed [the corresponding language proposal](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/39/non-breaking-spaces-and-punctuation-on-stack-exchange).

Comment: Aaw but those question marks are adorable! Please reconsider :`(

Comment: Maybe you hang out in a different place to me, but your question is the first I've seen in a very very long time with the upside down question mark. Is it really a problem?

Answer (score 11):

> This saves the editors from some extra effort.

Meh... Your example illustrates that these questions often need some editor-love anyway. In fact, there [were only nine uncorrected examples](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/114968/) lurking in the last data-dump. I'm really not sure this warrants any special consideration.