# Loss of periods from title end

Tags: bug

Periods on the end of title are lost upon submission, e.g. (amended to show minimal case):

[image]

gives

[image]

EDIT: This is not a case of "reduce any case where multiple question/exclamation marks are at the end of the title to a single instance." Nor of reduce any mark to a single instance.

Comment: I'm fairly certain it's by design. "..." Doesn't explain or clarify anything for the question

Comment: Not my downvote, but I suppose you could say which site you see this behaviour on. How long has it been happening.  Are you using the new theme? I dunno but it seems a bit bare.

Comment: I am not sure why one would require ellipses in the title. Could be a use case for a specific SE site I suppose

Comment: Rather than messing with the character limit for questions, you should add something about _why_ you really need that '...'

Comment: "I suppose you could say which site you see this behaviour on" Sorry, I thought that was obvious. This site. (And other *.stackexchange.com.)

Answer (score 6):

> Correct, why would anyone ever want that...

[(Jeff Atwood)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99871/can-should-we-get-rid-of-multiple-punctuation-marks#comment257408_100104)

Ellipses don't mean anything, and they sure can't be searched for.  Ideally, when people type their question titles, they're thinking about someone searching for the same question as they have.  This just can't happen with half-baked question titles that involve the use of ellipses.

Removing them is a passive prompt to define the question title properly (i.e. add whatever clarification the ellipses are replacing) and make the question title useful to those who follow and those happy few who search before posting.

Comment: When it comes to final periods, they're all removed. You can't end a question with even a single period.

Comment: "Removing them is a passive prompt to define the question title properly" It's no prompt at all. If the form wanted to prompt for alteration of the title, it should prompt.