# Why does the preview not show the title?

Tags: discussion, title, markdown-preview

(e.g. on this site.)

This omission hides the alterations that the site makes automatically and silently upon submission e.g. [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317036/loss-of-periods-from-title-end).

Comment: Don't know if it's the same for all browsers but on Firefox 62 it does... in the tab's name. (not optimal, but it's something)

Comment: Related if not dupe: [Please include the title in the question preview](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115247/398063) although it could use an update, the question is seven years old...

Answer (score 2):

Because that would costs space and it's not particularly useful. Contrary to the question body, which can contain markdown and [many more kinds of formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298843/295232), there's only a very limited amount of formatting that can be applied to the title; AFAIK only MathJax (and some, but not all communities discourage the usage of MathJax in titles). Therefore, you can predict fairly easily how a title will look like and a preview is not necessary.

Note that comments, which support a lot more formatting than titles, don't have a preview either. And if you don't like for whatever reason how a title is rendered, it's fairly easy to change it; it's only a few dozen characters, not the entirety of a post body.

Comment: Absence of formatting doesn't mean you can predict fairly easily how a title will look like. I can't predict what the auto-"correction" will do.

Comment: I have posted a separate feature request concerning MathJax: [Show a preview of the title when editing/asking - at least on the MathJax sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361217). (As you point out in your answer, it matters much less on sites where MathJax is not enabled.)